# how to make java class behave like a normal object and list-of-object at runtime and as per need?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I have a simple class in java like below:

```
class Simple {
   private String name;
   private String email;
}
```

I want to have behaviour of `java.util.List<Simple>` and `Simple` both according to input data that my program receives.

i.e.

Case 1::
if my program receives below kind of json-array input

```
{"simple" : [ {"name":"a", "email" : "a@z.com"}, {"name":"b", "email" : "b@z.com"} ]}
```

I need to parse it using **List<Simple>**

Case 2::
if my program receives below kind of json-object input

```
{"simple" : {"name":"c", "email" : "c@z.com"} }
```

I need to parse it using **Simple**

Note: I have tried using `JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`, but the problem is it is basically converting single value also into json-array at the time of writing json.
I need to persist json as it is, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any `Jackson` customisation I would create wrapper class with an `Object simple` property. We can add two extra checking methods and two extra casting methods. It will allow `Jackson` to do it's logic and in runtime we can check what actually we have:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DateApp {
    private final static JsonMapper JSON_MAPPER = JsonMapper.builder().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Simple object = new Simple("John", "john@doe.com");
        SimpleWrapper wrapper = new SimpleWrapper();
        wrapper.setSimple(object);

        serializeAndDeserialize(wrapper);

        wrapper.setSimple(Collections.singletonList(object));
        serializeAndDeserialize(wrapper);
    }

    private static void serializeAndDeserialize(SimpleWrapper wrapper) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = JSON_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        System.out.println("JSON:");
        System.out.println(json);

        wrapper = JSON_MAPPER.readValue(json, SimpleWrapper.class);
        System.out.println("Wrapper:");
        System.out.println(wrapper);
    }
}

@Data
class SimpleWrapper {
    private Object simple;

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isSimpleObject() {
        return simple instanceof Simple;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isSimpleList() {
        return simple instanceof List;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Simple getSimpleAsObject() {
        return (Simple) simple;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Simple> getSimpleAsList() {
        return (List<Simple>) simple;
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class Simple {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
JSON:
{
  "simple" : {
    "name" : "John",
    "email" : "john@doe.com"
  }
}
Wrapper:
SimpleWrapper(simple={name=John, email=john@doe.com})

JSON:
{
  "simple" : [ {
    "name" : "John",
    "email" : "john@doe.com"
  } ]
}
Wrapper:
SimpleWrapper(simple=[{name=John, email=john@doe.com}])
```

Comment: Thanks Michal for simplicity in solution, this is nearest to what i am thinking for handling this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JsonNode.isArray()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isArray()) (or `JsonNode.isObject()`) to perform this check.

Then you can parse the node into a list with [`ObjectReader.readValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)) or into a POJO using [`ObjectMapper.treeToValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode,%20java.lang.Class)).

```
String myJson = """
    {"simple" : {"name":"c", "email" : "c@z.com"} }
""";
    
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(myJson);

if (node.isArray()) {
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<Simple>>() {});
    List<Simple> list = reader.readValue(node);

    // do something with a list
} else {
    Simple pojo = mapper.treeToValue(node, Simple.class);

    // do something else with a single object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is able to parse any json into a map where value is any object. you can then inquire on the type of the map value

```
Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonInput, Map.class);
Object value = map.get("simple");
if (value instanceof Collection) { // will return false for null
    Collection<Simple> simples = (Collection<Simple>)value;
}
else if (value instanceof Simple) {
    Simple simple = (Simple)value;
}
else {
    System.err.println("unrecognized");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to read the first node, `simple` and check if it is an array - using `isArray()` method.

```java
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        //String inputString = [your input];
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(inputString);
    
        JsonNode simpleNode = root.findPath("simple");
    
        if(simpleNode.isArray()) {
    
           //you have an array

        } else {
    
        // you have an element
    
        }

    }
}
```